# Make ReSharper to avoid *.designer.cs files

Tags: resharper

How to make ReSharper 6.0 not to show some files (like *.designer.cs) in search results box (Ctrl+N)?

Comment: Do either of these questions help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005693/ignore-designer-and-generated-files-in-resharper-analysis, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612651/how-can-you-force-stylecop-for-resharper-to-ignore-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way you can skip a specified pattern of items in Go to File.
You can exclude certain files from code analysis and create from usage functionality but not from navigation.
What are you trying to find and why are the *designer.cs files an obstacle in your scenario?

Comment: When I find some control, ReSharper offers 2 files - Control.ascx.designer.cs at first place and Control.ascx.cs at second. So, I have to push additional arrow down to navigate. ReSharper 5.0 displays *.designer files at the last place, but 6.0 do it in another way.

Comment: Thanks, I see. We have a bug report on this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273698 This behavior should be fixed for version 6.1 due in September